# Show that the question "Is there life beyond earth?" is decidable

Tags: computability, turing-machines

I was given a question to prove that there exists a turing machine that solves the question

> Is there life beyond earth?

and is decidable. I actually don't understand how to show a turing machine decides this.

Thanks.

Comment: I'll argue that it is not decidable. Step 1: destroy all other life in the universe. Step 2: run the Turing machine. Step 3: launch an astronaut into deep space. Step 4: run the Turing machine again, from the same initial state. Since the outputs given at steps 2 and 4 were the same, and the correct answers were different, the Turing machine does not correctly solve the problem. (Trick questions deserve trick answers.)

Comment: The correct answer is a poor joke about a sloppy definition. A suitable definition of "decidable" would be that there is an algorithm that decides whether the given statement is true and not that there is an algorithm giving the correct result which is always the case because one algorithm produces "no" and the other "yes". Such a definition is completely useless because in this sense , almost EVERY yes-no-question is decidable.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is a trick question, the idea being that the answer doesn't depend on the input (or rather, has no input; but Turing machines are usually assumed to have an implicit input). If the answer is *YES*, then the Turing machine that prints *YES* solves the problem. The same goes for the answer *NO*. Of course, we don't know *which* of these two Turing machine solves the problem, but we know that one of them does.

In contrast, suppose you wanted to solve the halting problem in this way. Then you would need a table where for each program you record whether it halts on the empty input or not. This table is infinite, and so this approach doesn't work.

Comment: Instead of "doesn't depend on the input" it might perhaps be more accurate to say that there _isn't any input_ to depend on -- at least if by "input" we mean data that tell the machine which instance of the problem it's supposed to solve, because this problem has only one instance.

Comment: I appreciate that explanation. I think that particular question is not good suited as example of a constant machine function.

Comment: So the turing machine that solves the problem is decidable because it is a union of 2 turing machines that are decidable?

Comment: The assumption is that the question is equivalent to computing either $f() = 1$ or $f() = 0$. And for each $f$ there exists a Turing machine.

Comment: @mvw but then you assume that exists f that solves the question. It seems like Yuval Filmus gave a different answer.

Comment: The question can straightforwardly be answered by the Python (a Turing-complete language) expression `any(obj.location != Earth and obj.alive for obj in universe())`.  The only hard part is iterating every object in the universe.  But if you assume a finite universe, it's theoretically possible.

Comment: @Lee The more Turing style computable function might be $f : \Sigma^0 \to \{ \mbox{YES}, \mbox{NO} \}$. So there is only $f() = \mbox{YES}$ and $f() = \mbox{NO}$.

Comment: @Dan that is what I thought first, when I thought about the question. But this is not Yuval's explanation, which is a consequence of computing a function without input. Oh and `obj.alive` would be hard to implement as well.

Comment: @Lee No, it's not a "union" of anything. Because the answer is constant, you can hardcode it into a *single* Turing machine.

Comment: @mvw What do you mean by $\Sigma^0$ : $\emptyset$ or $\{\epsilon\}$?

Comment: The set of all words over sigma of lenght $0$, which is $\{ \epsilon \}$.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus I just don't understand, how do we implement a function/TM based on an answer that we don't know? or don't know how to find..

Comment: @Lee: You implement *both* TMs.  One of them is right.

Comment: @Kevin But how do I know which one is right? I mean, I need to implement 1 turing machine that solves the problem. So how does that turing machine decide?

Comment: @Lee: You don't.  But you don't need to.  One of them is right.  The question didn't ask you which one.

Comment: @Kevin Lets say I ask the machine for the answer and it says "Yes". So the answer might be not correct?

Comment: @Lee: Which machine?  You don't know which one is the correct one to ask in the first place.  But, again, you don't *need* that to answer the question, which is just "is there a correct machine?"

Comment: But the question asked for one turing machine that prints yes if is there life beyond earth and no otherwise..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24385/discussion-between-kevin-and-lee).

Comment: I remember this question from Sipser's book!  The way I convinced myself was that, in connection with this, the term "decidable" concerns the *Turing machine's* ability to determine the answer, not ours.

Comment: So basically, the problem is decidable by this machine?
    _If life does exist beyond Earth, Print "YES". 
    Else, Print "NO"_

Comment: @Lee, no you've completely misunderstood Yuval's solution. It goes like this. There are two cases; either the answer is yes, or the answer is no. If the answer is yes, then the Turing machine that prints "Yes" and does nothing else solves the problem. If the answer is no, then the Turing machine that prints "No" and does nothing else solves the problem. So in either case, there exists a Turing machine that solves the problem. Therefore, there exists a Turing machine that solves the problem.

Comment: **The fact that we don't know which case is the correct case, does not impact the existence of a correct case, nor does it impact the existence of a machine that correctly solves the problem.** It does, however, impact our ability to know *which* machine correctly solves the problem.

Comment: So is it a nondeterministic turing machine?

Comment: @Lee I am holding two Turing machines. One always prints _YES_. The other always prints _NO_. Now, I know that _one_ of these gives the correct answer, but I don't know which one. That doesn't matter, though; all you need to know is that one of these Turing machines solves it. That is, _there exists a Turing machine that solves it_. (Note that I'm holding _two different machines!_)

Comment: @Lee You're _not_ asked to specify a machine that works. You just need to prove that a machine that works exists.

Comment: The `If life exists beyond Earth print "yes" otherwise print "no"` machine _does not count_ because it is not a Turing machine.

Comment: Didn't think of the possibility before, but maybe OP's understanding of the question has to do with constructivism in some way?

Comment: It's just that classical logic can sometimes be unintuitive.

Comment: I think I might have diagnosed the misconception!!  I think the deciding TM (whichever one it is) looks illegitimate to the OP because it doesn't 'do' the right thing (such as (under the assumption of a deterministic, finite world) somehow deducing the positions and velocities of all particles and how they evolve over time and determining whether something that you declare to be RNA forms, etc., etc.; the TM obviously can't produce the answer by means of 'hardware' since life-finding capability is specified neither in the machine's definition nor as an oracle to it), because the spirit of the

Comment: solution feels repugnant even though the letter is correct, because it's 'morally' wrong.  I suspect he'd doubt or possibly disagree that the following procedure successfully decides whether $z=xy$ for integers:  Given representations of $x,y,z$, write $\sum_{i=1}^{|x+y|}(i+i+1)- \left( \sum_{j=1}^{|x-y|}(j+j+1) \right) -z-z-z-z$ on your tape (using some subTM or sequence of moves that does addition of integers); unless it is 0, reject, but accept otherwise.  The mechanism used may not obviously resemble what is popularly called school multiplication of x and y followed by comparison with z,

Comment: but it *effects* the correct result -- paralleling how $x \mapsto 2 \times x$ and $x \mapsto x+x$ are by definition one and the same function because what is meant by a function is purely extensional/black-box, what matters being the **ends** and not at all any '**means**' -- and to consider the algorithm intensionally would be meaningless and utterly infeasible (how could one judge its motive/intent or ascribe one to it?  what would count as a 'correct' one?), which is why we don't.  (However, under many definitions, problems need to have an infinite number of instances to qualify as such,

Comment: in which case one can't trivialise the problem by merely hardcoding all the solutions into a finite(ly describable) procedure, so in that sense a TM that decides the problem must, and could be said to, be doing 'the (or more properly, a) right thing' (or else it wouldn't work).)  So to resolve what I suspect to be the confusion, the essence is (tl;dr) *if a (fixed, independent of the choice of instance) TM always produces the correct output for a problem, then it is decidable, and if no such TM exists, then it is not; after that there can be no arguments*.  (Potentially adding to the confusion

Comment: is the faux-piecewise nature of the solution (which appears piecewise only to us, due to our agnosticism, but that is our 'fault' and not reality's, which is in no way affected by anyone's lack of knowledge; the answer is either fully yes or fully no, the branching having already taken place (by our being in this world and not an alternate one) without any visible sign, fully deterministic and without any superposed cats or other shenanigans.  The contingency is only in the *description* of the solution.).  But I do not believe it to be the primary culprit.)